# Cannot create a publicly accessible DBInstance because customer VPC has no - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I run my .json file inside cloud formation I get the following error "Cannot create a publicly accessible DBInstance because customer VPC has no internet gateway attached."

I deleted my default VPC in AWS then the customer support team recreated it for me but I still get the error.

These are the steps around the error

```
13:25:31 UTC+0000   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  pipindex    The following resource(s) failed to create: MyDB, InternetGateway, VPC. . Rollback requested by user.
13:25:30 UTC+0000   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::InternetGateway   InternetGateway Resource creation cancelled
13:25:30 UTC+0000   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::VPC   VPC Resource creation cancelled
13:25:30 UTC+0000   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::User  IMAUser 
13:25:29 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::User  IMAUser Resource creation Initiated
13:25:29 UTC+0000   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::RDS::DBInstance    MyDB    Cannot create a publicly accessible DBInstance because customer VPC has no internet gateway attached.
13:25:29 UTC+0000   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle    WaitHandle  
13:25:29 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::VPC   VPC Resource creation Initiated
```

Comment: do you try to set/create a new RDS instance in cloudformation?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that deleting the default VPC causes myriad problems.
I would make sure that they have re-created it in us-east-1
That seemed to help a great deal with that.
Hope that helps!